# Firestore - add timestamp type to a document inside my collection

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Tech: Angular 7, Firestore.

I can add a document to my collection but I need to add a field type timestamp in my document and im having trouble doing this.

**My Attempt:**

```
 item.datePosted = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

I need to use the type timestamp in firestore but it keeps adding type string for my datePosted field.

Comment: Try using `item.datePosted = new Date();` this will add the contents as a firestore timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp is a combination of date and time which is similar to the javascript `var date = new Date()` , in Typescript you can define the date datatype as `item.datePosted : Date = new Date()`;